# Average Household Power Usage - Distribution Spread

Tags: power

I'm trying to compare energy savings of solid state electric meters over older style electromechanical meters and am trying to find information on how long the average US household spends at each power level.

For example, if you replaced an electromechanical meter with a starting load of 24 watts with a solid state meter with a starting load of 5 watts you would be able to determine the associated savings by multiplying the current cost of energy times the amount of time the household spends below 24 watts minus the current cost of energy times the amount of time the house spends below 5 watts. These savings can come off the cost of the meter.

So what I'm looking for is a distribution curve that shows what percentage of the time an average household spends demanding X amount of power. Any leads?

Comment: I would think you would see some significant variation around any average based on geography- e.g. Phoenix vs New Orleans- and household income.  If you could find a daily usage graph, maybe you could extrapolate.

Comment: There will certainly be some significant geographically influenced variation, as well as seasonal. I think a good start would be an average across the country, throughout a year. I just don't know where this kind of data might be found!

Comment: Does this actually save energy, or just let you bill for previously ignored tiny amounts?

Comment: My house is never below 300 watts.  Just the cell phone and ipod chargers that are plugged in and not doing anything is probably 10 watts.  My Internet modem is probably another 10-20 watts.  Various Ethernet Switches and WiFi routers are another 20-30 watts.  Then there is the PC that is never turned off...

Comment: @David -- You need a new cell phone and ipod charger... ;-)

Comment: @pjc50- this only allows the utility to bill for previously unmetered usage, but (and not completely uncoincidentally) the newer meters are more energy efficient, which does save energy.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the *United States Energy Information Administration* (US-EIA).

They have a nice summary (with Excel formatted data) [here](http://www.eia.gov/tools/faqs/faq.cfm?id=97&t=3)

Comment: Seeing lots of good stuff there but not exactly what I'm looking for... I'll keep digging. Thanks.